# iOS Storyboarding segue action changes orientation incorrectly

Tags: ios, xcode

Okay so I'm new to the whole storyboarding functionality in iOS 5. I have an application for iPad that is locked into landscape mode. Just to test out the seguing functionality, I took my initial view controller, added a button, dragged a new view controller next to it (which shows up in landscape mode visually on the designer), then tied the segue action to the button. I left everything defaulted.

Hitting the button on the initial view controller initiates the segue with no problems, and the new screen loads up, but ALWAYS in portrait mode.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some toggle I'm missing? I figured that if via the summary of the project, I have it locked into landscape left and right, it would assume I always want that orientation unless otherwise noted? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an application for iPad that is locked into landscape mode.

How are you locking it app-wide? Just want to make sure you are doing it correctly.

To lock an orientation in Storyboard mode, select your ViewController and on the Attributes inspector change the Orientation from Inferred to whatever you want it to be locked to.

Comment: I probably used the wrong terminology here. By "locking" it I meant, I just set up the project's allowed orientation to landscape left and right. Let me try out what you said.

Comment: I did as you mentioned, clicked on the view controller and chose Landscape instead of inferred. Still flips it to portrait orientation every time the scene changes. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Allright I have it working now. I had the scene created but not the ViewController. Once I created that, I was able to programmatically stop it from changing orientation. Pain in the ass.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and managed it by adding a new own ViewControllerClass to the new scene.
Within the following auto created method, you can restrict the orientation to landscape only. This is also helpful for the Main Scene ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}
```

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: To clarify that point further: I had positive results just as soon as I took the newly created View Controller and assigned it to an existing class within my app (just the automatically created ViewController in my case). The place to do that is in the Identity Inspector within the Storyboard editor (over on the right) and change the class off of the UIViewController it was assigned by default.

Answer (score 1):

What have you put in the orientation delegate method?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: It was set to Return: YES. I changed it to what you have in your example above, however its sort of weird what happened. It DID fix it in the fact that now it stays in landscape no matter what, however all the page content on both view controllers is now in portrait mode. So its all on its side. What I need is for it to stay in landscape mode like this but for all content to be in landscape orientation as well. Please help? I can't believe how obtuse Apple has made this process.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties file for your app (YOURAPPNAME-Info.plist), located in the "supporting files" group, there is an array called "Supported interface orientations". Remove both landscape values from the array and your app will be locked in portrait orientation.